# New menu on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In XAML, is it possible to display a new "screen" when a button has been clicked?

Like for example, in Android apps, you click an option from the main menu and normally a new screen is displayed with different options.

I would like to to do this, I don't want new windows appearing, context menus is not quite what I want either.

Comment: Is this a WPF, Silverlight or Windows Phone application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx) populated with [TabItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.aspx) to switch "frames". You can add as many tabs as you like at design-time.

Then at run-time just change `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property of the tab control to redirect your user to the right tab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to try without tabs - I found these solutions which I will try first :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135113/how-do-you-do-transition-effects-using-the-frame-control-in-wpf

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the link, it's interesting.