# Why is the DoubleAnimation during Frame.Navigating event not starting?

Tags: wpf, animation, navigation, transition

I'm trying to create a fade in/out transition between page navigations with an implementation very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135113/how-do-you-do-transition-effects-using-the-frame-control-in-wpf).  Unfortunately, it is not behaving the way I intended. My code looks like this:

```
private void frame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = 1,
        To = 0,
        Duration = new Duration(Timespan.FromMillseconds(100))
    };
    animation.Completed += new EventHandler(animation_Completed);
    frame.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
}

private void animation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = 0,
        To = 1,
        Duration = new Duration(Timespan.FromMillseconds(100))
    };
    frame.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
}
```

It seems after the page is initially navigated to, the first animation does not start, but the second chained animation does start.  However, it behaves just the way I intended if I navigate by jumping back or forward.

The first animation is definitely being kicked off, because if I increase the duration to a more noticable time, say like 5 seconds, there is a 5 second delay before the second animation begins.

This issue is really stumping me. I haven't figured out what is different between the initial page navigation and the go forward/back navigations.

EDIT: After digging around some more, it seems the first animation does in fact occur, just I don't see it because it's the previous page. So my problem must be the animation is occuring after the new page is navigated to.

Comment: Your code has some typos. It should be, "TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARGH! If only I dugged around a little more before feeling a bit discouraged.

The trick to solve my problem was placing my animation in the Navigated event handler. The first animation to fade out the previous page was not needed to achieve the effect I was looking for. My code now looks something like this:

```
frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) 
{     
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation     
    {         
        From = 0,         
        To = 1,         
        Duration = new Duration(Timespan.FromMillseconds(100))     
    };     
    frame.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation); 
}
```

In the Navigating handler, the new page wasn't quite yet loaded and by the time I triggered the second animation it was loaded and starting the animation after it was loaded looked poor.

Comment: Your function here has the wrong parameters. It should read: private void frame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)