# WPF Window content navigation with slide in transition

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend-4

I have been having a hard time trying to implement content navigation (with slide in effect) inside a window just like the one in Visual Studio Ultimate Setup.exe using Microsoft Blend for Visual Studio 2013.

The installer is a available from here and demonstrates the effect I'm looking for:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40778

Please let me know if you know how to slide in another window content inside the same window as exhibited in the above setup file.

I would really appreciate it if you can show me how to do that in Blend editor visually instead of code. (I already tried displaying different pages inside a frame but I couldn't change the source of the frame inside the visualstate storyboard)

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is to use more than one navigation object. You have both on the page, but invisible. Then when they click NEXT, you use a storyboard to animate one off the screen and the next into the screen.

http://snsatyendra.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/create-navigation-using-fluid-ui-and-behaviors-in-wpf-and-silverlight/

I did something like this in Silverlight once. I had multiple usercontrols and just slide one off the screen and the other onto the screen. I had a reverse animation too. After the animation is finished, you can reset everything for the animation, setting the previous/next page contents ahead of time for the next animation trigger.

Also, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723946(v=Expression.40).aspx for the FluidMoveBehavior. That might help with animating.

Comment: I already had tons of examples and tutorials just like the one you had sent me over the past 2 days. They all are providing tips in general. I need that in the way as shown in the setup file. I also pointed out that I tried to change the source of a frame with a page inside it and mentioned that I couldn't change the source in the storyboard. Please provide a more specific answer please. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you change the target of the storyboard? I'm thinking that the article I linked to is a pixel effect, not a physical effect that you're looking for. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: target? no such property in frame

Comment: Target is who the storyboard is animating, so it's on the storyboard object that I was referring to. I think I misunderstood what you were asking. This question may give you some more information. This one may be a duplicate of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135113/how-do-you-do-transition-effects-using-the-frame-control-in-wpf