# Animation transitions between pages with Navigation Service

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice

I am using WPF in C# and NavigationService. For example:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new CategoryPage());
```

How can I add transition fade or any other animation to navigate between pages?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137596/2498426

It worked fine for me, but I had to replace ActualHeight by Height. However, the result is so choppy that I personnaly decided not to use animations at all.