# WPF Cell Phone UI (sliding screens)

Tags: wpf, user-interface, layout, slider, effect

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to create a cell phone like UI (specifically the sliding screen part). This is for a system tray tool that I am developing for an IT  support company. The WPF application looks like a cell phone, and contains various different buttons and data on the cell phone display. I actually have the app pretty much finished, but now they are wanting to change some stuff around and add more screens to it.

**What I have now:**

Picture an android cell phone on its home screen, then you swipe right and get a fresh set of icons and data. That's pretty much what this is like. I currently have 3 different screens, and I accomplished this by creating a Grid that was bigger than the view-able area. When you go to the next screen the grid's margin changes using a storyboard (so it looks like a swipe), and the next screen is then in the viewable area. The home screen is then to the left of the phone (hidden), and the 3rd screen is to the right of the phone (hidden as well).

Got an idea of what it's like now? If I did a horrible job explaining maybe I can upload something that shows the UI (just let me know).

**The problems I have with doing it this way:**

It was kind of a pain to get the three screens the way I wanted them because I had to manually change the margins so I could view the part of the grid that I needed to view and edit. When the app is running it's much easier to see them as you can just press a button and the screen moves for you. Now that I am adding even more screens it's even harder, and it just seems like there should be an easier way.

Does anybody know of any example WPF apps, templates, or controls that I could modify to work with something like this? How about just a suggestion on how I could build something from scratch that would be a little easier to modify and add to? Something that comes to mind is perhaps a way to do a separate control for each screen, and find a way to make one control slide out and the other slide in at the same time. It has to look like they are basically connected though.

Full disclosure: I'm not a developer. I'm a systems engineer that happens to be tasked with creating a custom system tray tool for our clients to start chat support sessions (among other things). Any help you can provide would be appreciated! I did try to search for this, but keep coming up with examples like volume control sliders (not cell phone UI like sliders).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx) to navigate between [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.aspx)s, (See [QuickStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)). This will do everything you need to handle the navigation between pages except for the transitions, but these can be applied using something like [this from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135113/how-do-you-do-transition-effects-using-the-frame-control-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DevExpress, you can use the DevExpress FlipView Control. By using flipview, you can add how many ever screens you want. While displaying, you can just hide the flip buttons, capture swipe or mouse movement and flip the view accordingly.

I have very limited knowledge on DevExpress controls. But as per my understanding, I thought flipview may be the right choice for your case.